# How do I pass parameters to cors within a firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, cors, axios, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send basic string parameters to cors which is within a firebase function. However I can't find a way to pass the parameters without the cors flaring up and blocking my request.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({origin:true})

exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  cors(request, response,() =>{
    var variableA = request.body.A
    var variableB = request.body.B
    var variableC = reques.body.C

    response.send("Function run completed")
  })
```

The Firebase function is being called using an axios.get()

```
axios.get('someURL', {
            A:variableA,
            B:variableB,
            C:variableC
        })
        .then(res => {
            const output = res.data;
            console.log("message output = " + output)
        })
```

The request and firebase function are working correctly and as expected. But I don't know how to pass the parameters through properly. Anyone know how to do this?

IMPORTANT EDIT! - I should add that the method shown in the code above results in the parameters being undefined. If I try to reference the request and response objects from the axios call in any way (the first pair of request and response objects), that is when the cors error flares up.

Comment: "I should add that the method shown in the code above results in the parameters being undefined" -> which method? What if you do `...cors(request, response,() =>{
    var variableA = request.body.A ... console.log(variableA);...` what do you see in the CF console?

Comment: I believe that that is what is being shown in the code above which is resulting in the variables being undefined. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I think part of your issue here is that you are looking in `req.body` for parameters on a `GET` request. `GET` requests should not have bodies (only query params) and while I'm not sure this is the cause of the issue it's probably not helping. I'd recommend using a `POST` or query params with `req.query` instead.

Comment: Yep that's a poor error on my part. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `axios.post()`: by doing `axios.get()` the `body` is not passed to the Cloud Function.

```
axios.post('someURL', {
            A:variableA,
            B:variableB,
            C:variableC
        })
        .then(res => {
            const output = res.data;
            console.log("message output = " + output)
        })
```

Comment: Yeah that's a poor error from me. Thank you for clearing that up for me